# How long does a Message stay hidden in an Azure Queue before it gets made visible again?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-queues

With any normal Azure Queue, I pop a message, then do some work. I didn't want to delete the message until after the work is done.

How long does that message stay *hidden* before it's deemed a failure and is made *visible* again on the queue?

eg.

```
var message = myQueue.GetMessage();

 // Do Work ..

myQueue.DeleteMessage();
```

My work could take .. 30 secs or something. or what happens if it took .. 1 min or 2?

I basically don't want the message to be come available again before the work is complete, incase another worker pops it off the queue .. even though this worker is still *doing work*.

Can we set the 'hide' time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Can we set the 'hide' time?

Yes. You can set the time for which a message will be hidden to other callers. If you look at the REST API documentation for [`Get Messages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179474.aspx), it expects a parameter called `visibilitytimeout`. This parameter is responsible for hiding the message for specified number of seconds. After that time period has elapsed, the message becomes visible again if not deleted.

> How long does that message stay hidden before it's deemed a failure
>   and is made visible again on the queue?

If you're using .Net Storage Client library, you have an option to specify the visibility timeout period. Take a look at the documentation for [`Get Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.getmessage.aspx) where you can specify the visibility timeout. Since this is an optional parameter in the library (but required at the REST API level), default value provided by the library is 90 seconds.

Comment: What happens if visibility timeout has expired, message is again visible and I try to delete that message because my work took more time than visibility timeout period?

Comment: When you dequeue a message (using Get Message), you get a `popreceipt` that you use to delete the message. This `popreceipt` remains valid till the time message is dequeued again. So as long as your message is not dequeued, you can delete the message even if the visibility timeout period has expired. Please read Remarks section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179347.aspx. HTH.

Comment: Based on your explanation, will INvisibility timeout(when invisibility expired) be more appropriate name?

Comment: Get Message link is broken. Should it be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.getmessage?view=azure-dotnet ?   Also where 90 sec visibility timeout default value came from?  according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Get-Messages visibilitytimeout default value is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 11):

You can specific a Visibility Timeout as a parameter to one of the GetMessage() overloads. You can also use UpdateMessage() to extend the invisibility of the message. However, you can never guarantee that the message will not be processed twice - e.g., the consumer dies having completed the work but before deleting the message. Windows Azure Queues is a best-effort FIFO queue - with at-least once semantics.

Comment: Is there a way to make the messages visible again, before that visibility timeout period has expired? Lets say I accidentally set the timeout to 3 days and want to look at the messages after just a couple of hours?

Comment: You could use CloudQueue.UpdateMessage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.updatemessage?view=azure-dotnet), setting the timeout to 1 sec to make it reappear real soon. Not sure of the use case for that, though, since you have to already have the message in order to shorten the time, exposing it to others.